# Resolving DNS lookup when using a proxy on a adhoc network

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, ad-hoc-network

I have a network with the following setup:

- Box A(client) has a local HTTP/S proxy running
- Box A is set to use 0.0.0.0:7777 as a HTTP/S proxy
- The proxy service forwards all traffic to box B(proxy) via wireless adhoc network
- A has no internet access, but B does and acts as a proxy
- B passes along A's request to C which performs the original HTTP request

When I try to make any kind of HTTP request from A, I'm told that it could not resolve the hostname `abc.com`.  My assumption is that the DNS servers for A are no longer accessible in adhoc mode which is why I get this error.  Assuming this is correct, how can I pass along or defer the DNS lookup to be proxied through B and C?  Is this possible or do I need to run a local DNS server that will redirect all requests back to 0.0.0.0:7777?

Is there a way to add a wildcard to my `host` file?  I need all HTTP requests to run through this proxy, not just a select few.

Comment: an option is to use the local `hosts` file on server A to get around needing dns servers.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is shorthand for 'unroutable'. Use a different address. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0